# New Regex() adds trailing slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to do a regexp in js on an email field.
this is what I have so far:

```
 var regex      = '[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}?$/g',
 emailRegex     = new RegExp(regex);
```

if I console.log() the emailRegex it returns:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}?$\/g/
```

What I want is:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}?$/g
```

As it is now it return the email is invalid error. Using https://regex101.com/ with the regexp I want (without trailing slash) works, using the regexp that gets returned in the console.log() says no match.

How can I remove the trailing slash from the RegExp?

Comment: `var regex      = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}?$',
 emailRegex     = new RegExp(regex, 'g');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that did it - new to regex, wasn't aware you could pass the global to the RegExp class haha #scrub :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/regularexpression/flags` format is the *literal* format for a regular expression; you don't use it if you're using the `RegExp` constructor; instead, you use two discrete strings: `new RegExp("regularexpression", "flags")`

So:

```
var regex      = '[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}?$',
emailRegex     = new RegExp(regex, "g");
```

Of course, in this case, there's no need for `new RegExp`:

```
var emailRegex = /[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,16}?$/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add flags to a literal regex you need to use the `/` literal form:

```
var r = /matching/g;
```

you can't supply flags when creating via a string except by explicit use of the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var r = new RegExp('matching', 'g');
```